# How do I create an array that has a size of 5 so it can hold the 5 numbers the user enters and then use a for loop to print out the contents?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have to store 5 unknown numbers in an array and then display the numbers after the user has entered the 5th number.

Can someone help me create an array that has a size 5 to it and then use a for loop to display the numbers.

The code I have so far is:

## Creating an Array

---

```
<p>Please enter a number between 1 and 5:</p>

<input id="number">

<button type="button" onclick="submitNumbers()">Submit</button>


<p id="demo"></p>

<hr>

<p>Please enter another number between 1 and 5:</p>

<input id="numbertwo">

<button type="button" onclick="submitNumberstwo()">Submit</button>


<p id="demotwo"></p>

<hr>

<p>Please enter another number between 1 and 5:</p>

<input id="numberthree">

<button type="button" onclick="submitNumbersthree()">Submit</button>


<p id="demothree"></p>

<hr>

<p>Please enter another number between 1 and 5:</p>

<input id="numberfour">

<button type="button" onclick="submitNumbersfour()">Submit</button>


<p id="demofour"></p>

<hr>

<p>Please enter another number between 1 and 5:</p>

<input id="numberfive">

<button type="button" onclick="submitNumbersfive()">Submit</button>


<p id="demofive"></p>

<hr>

<button onclick="revealNumbers()">Reveal Numbers</button>

<p id="numbers"></p>


<script>
function submitNumbers() {
var n, text;

// Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
n = document.getElementById("number").value;

// If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 5
if (isNaN(n) || n < 1 || n > 5) {
    text = "Please enter a valid number between 1 & 5!";
} else {
    text = "You have entered a correct number";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}

function submitNumberstwo() {
var n, text;

// Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
n = document.getElementById("numbertwo").value;

// If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 5
if (isNaN(n) || n < 1 || n > 5) {
    text = "Please enter a valid number between 1 & 5!";
} else {
    text = "You have entered a correct number";
}
document.getElementById("demotwo").innerHTML = text;
}


function submitNumbersthree() {
var n, text;

// Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
n = document.getElementById("numberthree").value;

// If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 5
if (isNaN(n) || n < 1 || n > 5) {
    text = "Please enter a valid number between 1 & 5";
} else {
    text = "You have entered a correct number!";
}
document.getElementById("demothree").innerHTML = text;
}

function submitNumbersfour() {
var n, text;

// Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
n = document.getElementById("numberfour").value;

// If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 5
if (isNaN(n) || n < 1 || n > 5) {
    text = "Please enter a valid number between 1 & 5";
} else {
    text = "You have entered a correct number!";
}
document.getElementById("demofour").innerHTML = text;
}

function submitNumbersfive() {
var n, text;

// Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
n = document.getElementById("numberfive").value;

// If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 5
if (isNaN(n) || n < 1 || n > 5) {
    text = "Please enter a valid number between 1 & 5!";
} else {
    text = "You have entered a correct number";
}
document.getElementById("demofive").innerHTML = text;
}

</script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is not working in your case ?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have to write a script to ask the user to enter a number between 1 & 5, five times. I have done this. The part i am stuck at is storing the numbers in the next array element. After the user has entered the 5th number I need to display the numbers like: Number 1 = n (n is the number they have entered) Number 2 = n Number 3 = n Number 4 = n Number 5 = n

Comment: Create an array: `var arr = []` and then `push` values into it: `arr.push(10)`.

Comment: Can you add the code you've written to your question?

Comment: I have entered the code i have in the question. I dont know if that code is correct as i am only just starting out in coding and its for part of a course i am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

(according to update in question)

Your fixed HTML:

```
<p>Please enter a number between 1 and 5:</p>
<input id="number">
<button id="btn1" type="button" onclick="submitNumbers()">Submit</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<hr>
<p>Please enter another number between 1 and 5:</p>
<input id="numbertwo">
<button id="btn2" type="button" onclick="submitNumberstwo()">Submit</button>
<p id="demotwo"></p>
<hr>
<p>Please enter another number between 1 and 5:</p>
<input id="numberthree">
<button id="btn3" type="button" onclick="submitNumbersthree()">Submit</button>
<p id="demothree"></p>
<hr>
<p>Please enter another number between 1 and 5:</p>
<input id="numberfour">
<button id="btn4" type="button" onclick="submitNumbersfour()">Submit</button>
<p id="demofour"></p>
<hr>
<p>Please enter another number between 1 and 5:</p>
<input id="numberfive">
<button id="btn5" type="button" onclick="submitNumbersfive()">Submit</button>
<p id="demofive"></p>
<hr>
<button onclick="revealNumbers()">Reveal Numbers</button>
<p id="numbers"></p>
```

Your fixed JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var numbers = []
    function submitNumbers() {
      var n, text;
      // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
      n = document.getElementById("number").value;
      // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 5
      if (isNaN(n) || n < 1 || n > 5) {
          text = "Please enter a valid number between 1 & 5!";
      } else {
          text = "You have entered a correct number";
          numbers.push(n);
          document.getElementById("number").setAttribute('disabled', true);
          document.getElementById("btn1").setAttribute('disabled', true);
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    }
    function submitNumberstwo() {
      var n, text;

      // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
      n = document.getElementById("numbertwo").value;

      // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 5
      if (isNaN(n) || n < 1 || n > 5) {
          text = "Please enter a valid number between 1 & 5!";
      } else {
          text = "You have entered a correct number";
          numbers.push(n);
          document.getElementById("numbertwo").setAttribute('disabled', true);
          document.getElementById("btn2").setAttribute('disabled', true);
      }
      document.getElementById("demotwo").innerHTML = text;
    }
    function submitNumbersthree() {
      var n, text;

      // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
      n = document.getElementById("numberthree").value;

      // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 5
      if (isNaN(n) || n < 1 || n > 5) {
          text = "Please enter a valid number between 1 & 5";
      } else {
          text = "You have entered a correct number!";
          numbers.push(n);
          document.getElementById("numberthree").setAttribute('disabled', true);
          document.getElementById("btn3").setAttribute('disabled', true);
      }
      document.getElementById("demothree").innerHTML = text;
    }
    function submitNumbersfour() {
      var n, text;

      // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
      n = document.getElementById("numberfour").value;

      // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 5
      if (isNaN(n) || n < 1 || n > 5) {
          text = "Please enter a valid number between 1 & 5";
      } else {
          text = "You have entered a correct number!";
          numbers.push(n);
          document.getElementById("numberfour").setAttribute('disabled', true);
          document.getElementById("btn4").setAttribute('disabled', true);
      }
      document.getElementById("demofour").innerHTML = text;
    }
    function submitNumbersfive() {
      var n, text;

      // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
      n = document.getElementById("numberfive").value;

      // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 5
      if (isNaN(n) || n < 1 || n > 5) {
          text = "Please enter a valid number between 1 & 5!";
      } else {
          text = "You have entered a correct number";
          numbers.push(n);
          document.getElementById("numberfive").setAttribute('disabled', true);
          document.getElementById("btn5").setAttribute('disabled', true);
      }
      document.getElementById("demofive").innerHTML = text;
    }

    function revealNumbers() {
      alert(numbers)
    }
</script>
```

So the main logic here is that you create an array (numbers) and push number to it if it's correct (between 1 & 5), then lock the input so user is unable to add multiple numbers from one input. The function revealNumbers() - alerts your array.

Comment: Do you see jQuery mentioned in the question or tags?

Comment: It is just using javascript, i havent got onto jQuery yet.

Comment: @M.Harrison You can upvote && accept my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: It wont let me for some reason, I will keep trying

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create the array:

```
var arr = [];
```

Then, for each `submitNumber` function you need to `push` that number to the array if it's within range:

```
arr.push(n);
```

Finally, your `revealNumbers` can simply use `join` to produce a string that you can add to the `#numbers` element:

```
function revealNumbers() {
  document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = arr.join(', ');
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jd7fsot6/3/)